# binding ngModel instead of value to a custom Angular directive for currency input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I'm currently using a custom mat-input-currency format directive to automatically format my field inputs to currency. the npm repo is found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-currency-format).

However, the directive binds the element data to `[value]` of the input i and I need to 2-way bind it to `[(ngModel)]`
the binding works but the currency format display doesn't show when it is first loaded, only when clicking on the input and then going blur. binding it to `[value]` however, displays it in currency format on load.

here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wnaxw?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I forked from the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmh5gw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
I tried writing a function maybe to tap into an onload event for the input but not sure how to go about that. is there a way to make it load with the ngModel formatted? the event doesn't seemed to kick off in the onload.

```
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="mpPatient.ssissdiawardLetter=='Y'" appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>SSI/SSDI Award Amount</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text"
         (onload)="onLoadCurrencyEvent($event, mpPatient.ssissdiawardAmount)"
          mvndrMatCurrencyFormat [allowNegative]="false" [currencyCode]="'USD'"
          [(ngModel)]="mpPatient.ssissdiawardAmount"
          (blur)="updateUSAmount($event, mpPatient.ssissdiawardAmount)">
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the directive you used which I can not found the source code in github, so I don't know what happened in this custom directive. And from your code, I think you can just you Angular `CurrencyPipe`, it will provide the formar you want.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput type="text"
      [value]="testvalue | currency:'USD'" />
</mat-form-field>
```

I forked you demo and just for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gatlt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: jeez. why didn't i think to pipe the display. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

literally 5 minutes after i posted this question, i came across the answer.
Just as simple as breaking the ngModel to its parts. which is property binding and event binding.
so my  `[(ngModel)]="mpPatient.ssissdiawardAmount"`
becomes

```
[value]="mpPatient.ssissdiawardAmount"
(input)="mpPatient.ssissdiawardAmount = $event.target.value"
```

or Kevin Zhang's answer works too.

hope this helps the next guy.